# Is there any free TI tool is available for reprogramming the CC2541 Bluetooth Low Energy chip...?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I have beacon which has Texas Instrument's BLE cc2541 chip in it. I want to reprogram its advertising packets. Is there any free TI tool available to reprogram it. I saw on there website and full packages are available, which is too costly rather i want only developement software to reprogram my beacon. Any help?

Comment: Asking us to find a tool is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You could try the TI E2E™ community, or perhaps electronics.stackexchange.com. Either way, it looks like you need to buy hardware to reprogram it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reprogram the microcontroller of the SensorTag (cc2541), you need to download the TI BLE Stack from this link:

http://www.ti.com/tool/ble-stack

The "Project" folder in the stack includes  a "SensorTag" project folder. There is a project file in this folder named "SensorTag.eww", where you can program the microcontroller in the way you want.

You need an IDE named IAR Embedded Workbench to open the project file and perform the embedded programming. Unfortunately, it is not open source, but you have 30-days free trial:

http://www.iar.com/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/8051/

Comment: Is IAR the only way to develop firmware for cc2541?

Comment: Yes, this is the only option

Comment: Oh my goat. Moving to nordic then. nRF51822 seems like a good replacement. I am still wondering why would TI do something like this.